# Angular Fire 7 query collection

Tags: angularfire

Ive been trying to get my head around v7 without too many docs available. Ive come up with code to (well trying too) query a collection and display in Angular (see below):

```
async getAppointments() {
const userId = await this.auth.currentUser?.uid;
console.log('Get Appointments: ' + userId);

const appRef = collection(this.afs, 'appointments')
const appQuery = query(appRef, where('uid', '==', userId));

const querySnapshot = getDocs(appQuery);
this.appt = (await querySnapshot).forEach((d) => {
  const id = d.id;
  const data = d.data as Appointment;
  console.log(id, "=>", data);

  return {id, ...data};
  
})
}
```

in the HTML *ngFor="let a of appt | async"

Firestore Timestamp: {{ a.start }}

Bt nothing shows. Im getting the document ID in the console log . Any ideas will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a bit of digging I finally cracked it....

```
async getAppointments() {
   // This retrieves the chosen collection
    const appointmentCollection = collection(this.afs, 'appointments').withConverter<Appointment>({
      fromFirestore: snapshot => {
        const { start, finish, comments } = snapshot.data();
        const { id } = snapshot;
        const { hasPendingWrites } = snapshot.metadata;

        return { id, start, finish, comments};
      },
      toFirestore: (it: any) => it,
    });
    const uid = await this.auth.currentUser?.uid

    
    const appQuery = query(appointmentCollection, where('uid', '==', uid));

    this.appointments = collectionData(appQuery).pipe(
        traceUntilFirst('appointments')
    )
    
  }
```

Appointment is from export type Appointment = {...}
appointments is an Observable<Appointment[]>

Used *ngFor in html to display the data.

Getting a single document was even easier...

```
userDoc: DocumentReference;
snapped$: any;

  async getUserDoc() {
    const userId = await this.auth.currentUser?.uid;
    this.userDoc = doc(this.afs, 'users/' + userId);

    this.snapped$ = (await getDoc(this.userDoc)).data();
  }
```

First checking I have the logged in userID.
Then `*ngIf="snapped$"` in html

hope this helps anyone else...